# Regular expression: the string must contains sequence of words

Tags: java

I have such code:

```java
        String regexp = "[\\w\\W]*(London)[\\w\\W]*(Paris)[\\w\\W]*";

        String test1 = "London Paris";
        boolean t1 =  Pattern.matches(regexp, test1);
        System.out.println(t1);

        String test2 = "London to Paris";
        boolean t2 =  Pattern.matches(regexp, test2);
        System.out.println(t2);

        String test3 = "from London to Paris";
        boolean t3 =  Pattern.matches(regexp, test3);
        System.out.println(t3);

        String test4 = "from (London) -> (Paris)";
        boolean t4 =  Pattern.matches(regexp, test4);
        System.out.println(t4);
```

I need all boolean to be true. Now, this condition is met, but the regex seems to me not too effective. How can I change this?

Comment: Define "not too effective". Effective means *successful in producing a desired or intended result*. This produces the intended result.

Comment: `[\\w\\W]` matchs all characters, right? Why don't just use `.` (dot) instead?

Comment: I mean the beauty of the code. In my decision I am confused by the repeatability of `[\\w\\W]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to use word boundaries as well. Like this regex:

```
.*\b(London)\b.*(Paris)\b.*
```

The reason is that you current regex will also match `LondonaParis` or `aLondona   Parisaaa`. Not sure if you want that.

If you keep a word boundary around the specific names you are looking for, these strings won't pass.

However, I second @Ali Ben Zarrouk's point of not needing regexes for this.

Answer (score 5):

You can go with something faster than a regex:

```
public static boolean isValid(String str) {
        int indexOfLondon = str.indexOf("London");
        int indexOfParis = str.indexOf("Paris");

        return indexOfLondon != -1 && indexOfParis != -1 && indexOfLondon < indexOfParis 
    }
```

Regex is avoidable here.

Comment: But thats cheating! Regexes are fun! Just kidding :)

Comment: @Amongalen they are :) fun and challenging but first rule from a regex expert I heard was to avoid it as much as you can because of how confusing and slow it can be.

Comment: I've heard something along the lines: "If you have a problem and you think you can solve it with with regex then you have two problems"